# access denied localhost mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect with mysql localhost database.
But I am getting error using this string:

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://root@localhost:3306/mytestdb?password=secret&useSSL=false"
```

can somebody tell me if there is something wrong with this string.

Comment: add your error stacktrace to understand at ease

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did not define the username. It should be like:

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://root@localhost:3306/mytestdb?password=secret&user=UserName&useSSL=false"
```